# If there is too many 9s after a certain point do something

Tags: javascript, discord.js, mathjs

So basically there is an issue with math js where id it has to do this equation 1:999 or anymore nines it will crash.

```
        try
        {
            if(args == "1:999") return message.channel.send('That question is not allowed');

        } catch(error){
            message.channel.send("there was an error")
        }
```

Right now if you have it calculate 1:999 it gives an error, but I want it instead to see if the equation has any more nines. ex if i did 1:9999999 it would also give an error but basically anything over with more than three nines in this equation will give an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) being used to test if a string is of the form "1:999", "1:9999", "1:99999", ...

```js
if (/^1:999+$/.test(arg)) {
```

Comment: Thanks you for the help, I'm kind of new to JavaScript and never knew this existed. I would upvote, but I don't have enough "reputation"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`String#EndsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) to check if the string ends with the number of `9` you want using [`String#repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

```
if (args.endsWith('9'.repeat(count))) {
  console.log("Too many nines");
}
```